# How to properly use/plug Redis with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, redis

I have a Rails application that I want to connect to a Redis data structure server. I'm wondering how I should proceed. I'm using a global variable `$redis` locate at `config/initializers/redis.rb` to make queries across the entire application.

I believe this approach it is not suitable for a application with 80+ simultaneous connections, because it uses one single global variable to handle the Redis connection.

What should I do to overcome this problem? am I missing something about Rails internals?

Tutorial I'm following
http://jimneath.org/2011/03/24/using-redis-with-ruby-on-rails.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the application server you will use. If you're using [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/) which is a popular choice you should be fine.

Unicorn forks it's workers and each one will establish it's own database connection. And since each worker can only handle one request at a time it will only need one connection at a time. Adding more connections won't increase performance, it just will open more (useless) connections.

ActiveRecord (which is the DB-part of Rails) or DataMapper support [connection pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) which is a common solution to overcome the problem you've mentioned. Connection pooling however [only make sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663529/really-need-a-db-connection-pool-for-unicorn-rails) in a threaded environment.

On top of that Redis is mainly single threaded (search for "Single threaded nature of Redis") so there might be no advantages anyway. There was [an request to add connection pooling](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/issues/171) but it got closed, you might get more information from there.

Comment: Thank you, with your answer I was able to do some research and ended up using Unicorn. Although with Unicorn now I have memory issues, I learned that Ruby does not release the memory back to the Operative system, but instead reuses it, which is a big problem for me, because every fork Unicorn make, consumes as much memory as the Parent process. Last time I checked a single process of my application consumes +90mb, multiply that number by the number of process forked and becomes a considerable amount of memory, in the mean time, I'm doing `GC.start` after each fork.

Comment: @Kira Do you use Ruby 2? If not [you should (see part about Copy-On-Write)](http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/3/23/why-you-should-be-excited-about-garbage-collection-in-ruby-2-0) and I think GC.start after forking isn't really useful, but [Unicorn’s out-of-band GC](http://blog.newrelic.com/2013/05/28/unicorn-rawk-kick-gc-out-of-the-band/) might be.

Comment: Yes I'm using Ruby 2 for the same reasons you said; CoW. Although I was not aware of the "out of band GC" and that `GC.start` could be a bad idea; such a wonderful link the one you provided. Many thanks, 2called-chaos.